# all_of function to check condition in all elements of part of an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops

The following code checks if all elements in the declared array are odd numbers.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::all_of
#include <array>        // std::array

int main () {
    std::array<int,8> foo = {3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23};

    if ( std::all_of(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](int i){return i%2;}) )
        std::cout << "All the elements are odd numbers.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

(Sample taken from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/all_of)

I would like to check if **all elements in the declared array starting from `foo[2]`** are odd numbers.

Replacing `foo.begin()` with `foo[2]` does not work. I've tried many other things to make this work, all very basic (very basic C++ user here), without success. I do not want to resize the array for achieving this.

Ultimately what I'm looking for is having a loop where a condition is checked for on **every** element of part of an array, just as the `for` loop checks for a condition on **any** element of part of an array. This is relatively easy to achieve in R, and I'm hoping it may be equally easy to achieve in C++.

Comment: Replacing `foo.begin()` with `foo.begin() + 2` ?

Comment: Thank you. That worked! Spent the whole day on this. Cheers.

Comment: `foo.begin()` is an `iterator`, `foo[2]` is the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use an iterator and an element here, they don't represent a range. In a more general sense, even attempting to use a pointer to an element and an iterator would not be well defined for all implementations of any given container either.

You should use `std::next(it.begin(), 2)` to increment to the `begin()` iterator to the `foo[2]` element and then you can iterate over the range with the two iterators.

```
std::all_of(std::next(foo.begin(), 2), foo.end(),
  [](int i){/*...*/})
```

[`std::next()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) is more general and caters for iterators other than just random access iterators (e.g. for the alternate `it.begin() + 2`); but will still be performant for the type of iterator passed to it.

Comment: Any benefits over just `foo.begin() + 2` ?

Comment: For the random access iterator you have, it'll land up being the same thing. I prefer the use of next for more robust code if the container changes, and other maintenance changes etc. and some personal preference for code clarity in the reading of the code. Both will work as you expect.

Comment: @Niall - on the other hand, if the container changes to a type that does not provide random access iterators, `std::next` will introduce a (potentially large) performance hit, while `begin() + 2` won't compile.

Comment: If the container type or iterator type is crucial, a `static_assert` with a clear message on the expected types would be better than a compilation error on the `begin() +2`, that error may appear unrelated.